# Git Cannot push to forked repo on github

Tags: git, github

So I forked a project in github, and cannot push my local changes to my origin repo because of errors during the 'push' command requiring that I first do a 'pull'.  Well the problem is the 'pull' keeps overwriting all of my local commits.

Example shown below:

There is a project A (remote = upstream) on github that I forked into my own project (remote = origin).  I then created a branch "branch_a" in which I added all my patch changes and pushed this branch to my remote origin repo.  I ended up botching this whole process with multiple commits so I needed to squash my commits into one in order to submit a Pull Request to send my changes to project A.  Attempts to squash my commits and synch with upstream repo went as follows:

> git rebase -i upstream/master

I saw 4 commits and picked the one I wanted and removed the others

> git push origin branch_a

Received error:

> ! [rejected]        branch_a -> branch_a (non-fast-forward)
>   error: failed to push some refs to 'https://github.com/#####/#####.git'
>   To prevent you from losing history, non-fast-forward updates were rejected
>   Merge the remote changes (e.g. 'git pull') before pushing again.  See the
>   'Note about fast-forwards' section of 'git push --help' for details.

Ran the pull command:

> git pull origin branch_a

Received message:

> - branch            branch_a     -> FETCH_HEAD
>     Merge made by recursive.
>     libpex/INSTALL |  364 +++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++
>     1 files changed, 364 insertions(+), 0 deletions(-)
>     create mode 100644 libpex/INSTALL

Local commit completely overridden by the pull command (I have tried to delete this file about 10 times but it keeps coming back).

So now I'm back to having 4 commits again and I cannot for the life of me push the correct commit back to my origin repo.  What can I do about this?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you want to tell Git to push what you have and overwrite whatever is at the destination (this can destroy history, so use it carefully) then supply `--force` to your push statement:

```
git push --force origin branch_a
```

This will cause the `origin/branch_a` branch to be updated to point at your local `branch_a` branch, regardless of whether or not it is a fast-forward.  **Any commits reachable from `origin/branch_a` that are not also reachable from your local `branch_a` branch or any other remote branch will be lost in the remote repository.**

Comment: Thanks that worked, however before accepting this answer, could you explain why I should need to do this?  Seems like either I was in a bad state or something is wrong with the Git UI if I have to use a '--force' option to what seems to be a routine operation.

Comment: The problem is that you pushed commits on `branch_a` and then rewrote history in some way -- you altered the past of `branch_a` and so the push was no longer a fast-forward.  Any time you rebase a branch, you alter its history.  This is why it's recommended to avoid rebasing branches you've already pushed somewhere else.  You not only need to force the push, but anyone who was forked from your branch is now screwed because the history they have for your branch no longer matches what you have.

Comment: Okay maybe this is a problem with the process defined by the developers of the main project.  What they told me to do was fork the repo, make changes, then create a pull request with one commit.  Then they gave me feedback on the patch so I did a rebase followed by my fixes and tried to re-submit a pull request but the push began failing.  My forked repo isn't an issue though since I'm working on it alone.  But I think your explanation does make sense.  Thanks.

Comment: Strictly, they won't be lost; they will be orphaned.  They are still recoverable until the next `git gc` is done if you know the commit id, which you can see with `git reflog` (a history of all the heads you have checked out).  Obviously on github you don't have shell access so this point is moot.  But it's important to remember that a `git push -f` (or a local `git reset --hard`) isn't as destructive as you might have been led to believe.

Comment: Yes, of course you can recover things from the reflog.  I'm not saying "this is unrecoverable," but rather "you are changing the history of your branch in ways that may affect other people."

Comment: You could also create a feature branch in your local fork (ie. `yourname/work`), send the initial pull request from that branch, then also commit any changes to it that arise during the review process.
Once the upstream maintainer accepted your patches, you merge their latest upstream into your `yourname/master`, apply all your changes as a single commit and send a new pull request from that.
Then you won't lose any history.